# How do you update a DateTime field in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, types

The following query does not update the datetime field:

```
update table
SET EndDate = '2009-05-25'
WHERE Id = 1
```

I also tried it with no dashes, but that does not work either.

Comment: is date the actual column name?

Comment: not actually, it is EndDate, but I just shortened it to Date.

Comment: do you get an error or just no results?

Comment: What's the data type for the `EndDate` column?

Comment: It says 1 row affected, but when I check, the date has not changed.

Comment: The data type for EndDate is DateTime.

Comment: You should post the actual SQL Statement that isn't working.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

When in doubt, [be explicit about the data type conversion using CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
UPDATE TABLE
   SET EndDate = CAST('2009-05-25' AS DATETIME)
 WHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: great thanks works well in SQL server 2016. I just use variables and all set.

Comment: I used that and added the time after the date and it worked

Answer (score 44):

Normally, it should work.

But can you try this? I don't have SQL on my home PC, I can't try myself

```
UPDATE table
SET EndDate = '2009-05-25 00:00:00.000'
WHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: This worked, but I tried it before without all zeros and it did not work. Why?

Comment: I tried it with '2009-05-25 00:02:01.000', but it didn't work.

Comment: Nice, seriously dont have any idea. Because you wrote without time information, and SQL must attach default 00:00:00.000 automaticly. So it must be worked.

Answer (score 12):

The string literal is pased according to the current dateformat setting, see [`SET DATEFORMAT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx). One format which will always work is the '20090525' one.

Now, of course, you need to define 'does not work'. No records gets updated? Perhaps the `Id=1` doesn't match any record...

If it says 'One record changed' then perhaps you need to show us how you verify...

Comment: The date format is why I was thinking being explicit about the conversion would be a good idea...

Comment: Good stuff Remus, `SET DATEFORMAT` is really effective when writing SQL for environments with different localizations

Comment: Awesome!  This worked for me and saved me a few steps because the field I'm converting was already using this format, i.e., no need to convert it to ISO or other format first.

Answer (score 10):

Using a DateTime parameter is the best way.
However, if you still want to pass a DateTime as a string, then the CAST should not be necessary provided that a language agnostic format is used.

e.g.

Given a table created like :

```
create table t1 (id int, EndDate DATETIME)
insert t1 (id, EndDate) values (1, GETDATE())
```

The following should always work :

```
update t1 set EndDate = '20100525' where id = 1 -- YYYYMMDD is language agnostic
```

The following will work :

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english
update t1 set EndDate = '2010-05-25' where id = 1
```

However, this won't :

```
SET LANGUAGE british
update t1 set EndDate = '2010-05-25' where id = 1
```

This is because 'YYYY-MM-DD' is not a language agnostic format (from SQL server's point of view) .

The ISO 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss' format is also language agnostic, and useful when you need to pass a non-zero time.

More info : http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE TABLE
   SET EndDate = CAST('2017-12-31' AS DATE)
 WHERE Id = '123'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't interested in specifying a time, you can also use the format '**DD/MM/YYYY**', however I would stick to a **Conversion** method, and its relevant ISO format, as you really should avoid using default values.

Here's an example:

`SET startDate = CONVERT(datetime,'2015-03-11T23:59:59.000',126)
 WHERE custID = 'F24'`

Answer (score 2):

That should work, I'd put brackets around [Date] as it's a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Is there maybe a trigger on the table setting it back?